# Flask-assets not resoving correct url

Tags: python, flask

[image]

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. I'm currently trying to add a new theme which I got from https://bootswatch.com called 'spacelab'. I've added a new directory 'spacelab' and copied and pasted the 2 bootstrap css files into it as you can see in the screenshot.

In the case there is an assets.py file that contains:

```
from flask_assets import Bundle, Environment

# skinning go to https://bootswatch.com/ add to libs/bootstrap/dist/css/

css = Bundle(
    "libs/bootstrap/dist/css/spacelab/bootstrap.css",
    "css/style.css",
    "css/home.css",
    # "css/style.css",
    filters="cssmin",
    output="public/css/common.css"
)

js = Bundle(
    "libs/jQuery/dist/jquery.js",
    "libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "js/plugins.js",
    filters='jsmin',
    output="public/js/common.js"
)

assets = Environment()

assets.register("js_all", js)
assets.register("css_all", css)
```

When I run it I see :

[image]

If I change

```
"libs/bootstrap/dist/css/spacelab/bootstrap.css"
```

to

```
"libs/bootstrap/dist/css/dark/bootstrap.css"
```

for example it works normally. Why is flask-assets not resolving the url correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the file name in your **spacelab** directory is **boostrap.css** and not **bootstrap.css**. :D

Comment: Aaagghh.. Thank you.